# Simple synchronization in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I was studying the Oracle documentation about the synchronization and there was this class counter :

```
class Counter {
    int c = 0;

    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

And they explain a little about some possible bad interleavings with two Threads, I tried to write a program to test these bad interleavings :

```
public class TestPara {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        AdderCounter ac = new AdderCounter(counter);
        SubberCounter sc = new SubberCounter(counter);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(ac);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(sc);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println(counter.c);
    }   
}

class AdderCounter implements Runnable{
    Counter counter;

    public AdderCounter(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        counter.increment();
        System.out.println(counter.value());
    }
}

class SubberCounter implements Runnable{
    Counter counter;

    public SubberCounter(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        counter.decrement();
        System.out.println(counter.value());
    }
 }
```

But no matter if the access to c is synchronized or not I always get the values 0, 0 and 0, and I don't know why.

Someone could help me ?
Best regards.

Comment: You're not running it often enough for the issue to occur.

Comment: You are just adding one and subtracting one **once**. The chances of an interleaved add/sub causing a multithreading issue is tiny in this case. Try running millions of add/subs in two different threads at the same time and see what happens.

Comment: I can get `1,0,0`, `0,1,0` and `0,0,0` just by running the program a few times.

Comment: Run it increment / decrement in a loop 10 million times. The final result should still be zero if there was no interleaving problem, but it won't be zero. Also, when you print, prefix the output with something recognizable so you know what the line that you're looking at means.

Answer (score 2):

Coincidence, this is the result on my machine:

```
1
0
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

And, if you try a lillte more,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Counter counter = new Counter();
    AdderCounter ac = new AdderCounter(counter);
    SubberCounter sc = new SubberCounter(counter);
    Thread t1 = new Thread(ac);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(sc);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    System.out.println(counter.c);
    System.out.println();
}
```

You may get this:

```
1
0
0

-1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

-1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

-1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

-1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

-1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

-1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0

1
0
0
```

Comment: I got the same result.

Comment: @khelwood Another coincidence :)

Comment: The first two of each triplet is the `println` in the thread. The last is the final count which is `0` in all cases here indicating no interleaving.

Comment: It's actually very strage, if I set it in a loop, I never get the three zeroes 
 (all of you are right) but I can press the button so many time I want, I always get these zeroes... So I suppose I haven't press enough time but it's really strange that I never get the three zeroes in the loop, no matter

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the add/sub **many** times in parallel.

```
private static final int COUNT = 1000000;

class Counter {
    int c = 0;

    public void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public int value() {
        return c;
    }
}

class AdderCounter implements Runnable {
    Counter counter;

    public AdderCounter(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            counter.increment();
        }
    }
}

class SubberCounter implements Runnable {
    Counter counter;

    public SubberCounter(Counter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            counter.decrement();
        }
    }
}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Counter counter = new Counter();
        AdderCounter ac = new AdderCounter(counter);
        SubberCounter sc = new SubberCounter(counter);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(ac);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(sc);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println(counter.c);
    }
}
```

For one run this printed:

> -33852
>
> 28937
>
> -546
>
> -678544
>
> -653775
>
> 358351
>
> -593183
>
> 1000000  <-- Now that's a REAL coincidence :)
>
> -826735
>
> -773183

for me where you would expect `0` if no thread contention occurred.

BTW: Don't add `println` statements in your tests - using IO while testing makes interleaving **much less likely** because most of the time the code will be doing I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the worst thing about bugs in concurrent programs is that very often they won't show up. You can run the program thousands of times on your local machine and it works just fine. Then you move it to some server which is accessed by millions of ppl and things starts to break "for no reason".